# regular expression validation failed on empty space

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am using phone validation regular expression in data annotation.
Phone validation is working fine but if i enter only empty space validation is not working.

Here is my regex

```
^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$
```

Comment: Please provide some examples with expected output ...

Comment: What do you mean by: `validation is not working.`?

Comment: It appears by the regex that you're expecting international numbers. International phone numbers do not always conform to the American format. Some have less or more digits and they are often grouped in various different ways, not necessarily utilizing the same punctuation you see in American numbers. If you need to validate phone numbers that could be international, you should look into a library like the .NET port of Google's libphonenumber: https://www.nuget.org/packages/libphonenumber-csharp

Answer (score 0):

Use masked input plugin of jquery.download it form nuget.it would be better.try this:

In your view :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#contactNumber").mask("(999) 999-9999");
  });
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>


@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactNumber)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContactNumber, "Contact Number :", new { style = "display:inline;" })
@Html.TextBox("ContactNumber", Model.ContactNumber, new { id = "contactNumber" })
```

In Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Number Required")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Entered phone format is not valid.")]
public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, your regular expression is not validating for empty spaces because the bold portions cannot match emptiness:

```
    ^
    \s*
    (?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?
    [-. (]*
    (\d{3})
    [-. )]*
    (\d{3})
    [-. ]*
    (\d{4})
    (?: *x(\d+))?
    \s*
    $
```

If you want to match the pattern, or nothing, you could make a simple modification:

```
^(?:\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*)?$
```

However on the more general problem of attempting to validate an international phone number, I'd agree with the commenters that this is difficult, and it may be one that's not be worth solving. You might want to just validate simpler things, like:

1. Starting with a + is fine.
2. The rest is made of numbers, which may or may not be interspersed with dashes or spaces.

Also, not sure if you want to handle extensions in there ("48204020420 x14" or such), but this gets really complicated really fast.